# How do I regex {% anything here %}?

Tags: regex, django

I need to regex `(% %)`

e.g. I want to regex match `{% this %}` or `{% anything really %}`.

Comment: could you post an example with the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just use the below if you can use groups

```
/\{([^}]+)}/g
```

Or else you can use the below if you just want the match without groups.

```
/(?<=\{)[^{}]+(?=\})/g
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://regex101.com/r/tL3iL8/1) & [**2**](http://regex101.com/r/tL3iL8/2)

Answer (score 0):

You just simply use

```
\{\%(.*?)\%\}
```